# hitTestForEvent:inRect:ofView is invoked twice in my NSOutlineView cells

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've subclassed the cells of a NSOutlineView, by setting the custom class in interface builder.

I've implemented this delegate method to configure the cells:

```
- (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView willDisplayCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item
```

Also, I've implemented this method in my custom cell class:

```
- (NSUInteger)hitTestForEvent:(NSEvent *)event inRect:(NSRect)cellFrame ofView:(NSView *)controlView
```

which is invoked twice every time I click on the cell. I'm wondering why not just once. The event type is always MouseDown.

I don't know if this matters, but it is invoked twice even if the cell has not parents or children. So it can't be the cells hierarchy.

If I can't rely on hitTestForEvent to trigger an action when a specific area of my cell is clicked, which method should I use ?

Thanks

Comment: if you are sure you hit this 2 times every time then use a flag (shouldPerformAction) inside the hittest and on the first hit perform the action you want and set the flag to false and in the second hit just set the flag to true.

Comment: @alinoz Ya, this is what I'm doing, but it is kinda a hack

Comment: what is the view? maybe you get one event for one subview and one for the parent view. do an nslog on the controlView class

Comment: @alinoz It happens also if I have only one item, the root, with no parent or children. That's why I've added it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-hitTestForEvent:inRect:ofView` is *entirely* the wrong method to be using to trigger actions.  You should be using `-trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:`, *or* `-startTrackingAt:inView:`, `-continueTracking:at:inView:` and `-stopTracking:at:inView:mouseIsUp:`.

**Important Note:** If you implement your own mouse tracking loop in `-trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:`, **you should document this fact somewhere**, because generally speaking it will preclude the use of the other three methods. Some of the `NSCell` subclasses in the AppKit framework do this and fail to document that they have done so (with the result that you’ll ponder for hours why it is that `-startTrackingAt:inView:` never gets called).

How do you implement your own tracking loop? Like this:

```
- (BOOL)trackMouse:(NSEvent *)theEvent inRect:(NSRect)cellFrame
            ofView:(NSView *)controlView untilMouseUp:(BOOL)untilMouseUp
{
  NSPoint pos = [controlView convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow]
                                 fromView:nil];

  if ([theEvent type] == NSLeftMouseDown && NSPointInRect (pos, myClickRect)) {
    NSWindow *window = [controlView window];
    NSEvent *myEvent;
    NSDate *endDate = [NSDate distantFuture];

    while ((myEvent = [window nextEventMatchingMask:(NSLeftMouseDragged
                                                     |NSLeftMouseUp)
                                          untilDate:endDate
                                             inMode:NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode
                                            dequeue:YES])) {
      if ([myEvent type] != NSLeftMouseUp)
        continue;

      pos = [controlView convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow]
                             fromView:nil];

      if (NSPointInRect (pos, myClickRect)) {
        // React somehow
      }

      return YES;
    }
  }

  return [super trackMouse:theEvent inRect:cellFrame ofView:controlView
              untilMouseUp:untilMouseUp];
}
```

(The above code was just typed in here, so the usual caveats apply; it assumes the existence of an `NSRect` called `myClickRect` that defines the active area of your cell. You might need to calculate that from `cellFrame` at the head of the method.)

Obviously you can watch for and handle other events too, if they are relevant to you.

Perhaps I should also add that the three method approach, while conceptually cleaner, tends to be quite a bit slower, which generally leads me to prefer overriding `-trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:` as shown above.

Comment: Thanks for the long answer. I've overridden -(BOOL)trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp: but it is never invoked. I haven't used the other methods, do you know what could be the reason ?

Comment: Is maybe because the super class is a NSTextFieldCell ?

Comment: Same thing for - (BOOL)startTrackingAt:inView: , continueTracking:at:inView: and stopTracking:at:inView:mouseIsUp: They are never invoked

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any typos in the method names? It can be quite frustrating if they're wrong (check the documentation carefully against your code).

Comment: Also, for `NSOutlineView`, you may need the delegate to return `YES` to `-outlineView:shouldTrackCell:forTableColumn:item:`.  It depends on whether you want to track the mouse only for selected cells or not.