# -(BOOL)trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp: Is never invoked

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscell, nscontrol

I have subclassed NSControl to get my custom control,
        have subclassed NSCell to get my custom cell,
        over overridden `-(BOOL)trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp` and necessary methods 
        in custom cell,
        have overridden `+ (Class)cellClass` in customControl to return my customCell,

Cell draws fine on control, set enable, set dissable works fine, but
        Mouse events not getting triggered.
        While debugging i noticed that `-(BOOL)trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:`
        is never invoked. As per "Control and cell programming guide" -

> "Controls manage the behavior of their cells. By inheritance from
>   NSView,
>            controls  derive the ability for responding to user actions and rendering their 
>            on-screen representation. When users click on a control, it responds in part 
>            by sending `trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:` to the cell that was clicked"

Kindly tell if i am missing something - i have googled a lot got nothing useful.

Comment: did you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649379/hittestforeventinrectofview-is-invoked-twice-in-my-nsoutlineview-cells)

Comment: Yes, they have also mentioned that -(BOOL)trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp not getting called, but nobody gave any answer:(. And i am not using NSOutLineView here i am using this custom cell in my own custom control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this example here https://github.com/mtavkhelidze/MTControlWithCell

Comment: Thank you, bit late but very useful.